# Mostrar u ocultar div en Angular si tiene o no información un input

Tags: angular, typescript

Hola quiero mostrar u ocultar un div, dependiendo si tiene o no información desde el servidor.

Me explico, tengo un formulario que al hacer una llamada al servidor me devuelve unos datos, en esos datos hay un input que esta dentro de un div y debe mostrar la información de las corporaciones pero a veces no existen esas corporaciones entonces lo que busco es que si ese input tiene información me lo muestre y si no tiene entonces oculte el div.

Aquí mi HTML

Quiero ocultar todo el div donde esta el *ngIf

```
<div *ngIf='showDiv()' >
    <div class='col-6'>
      <label for='corporation'>Corporación</label>
      <input type='text' fullWidth disabled id='corporation'>
    </div>
    <div class='col-6'>
      <label for='employee'>Empleado</label>
      <input type='text' fullWidth [value]='corp.employee?.name' disabled id='employee'>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Y en el TypeScript tengo la siguiente función, aquí me esta mostrando en la consola cuando tiene me muestra que si tiene y cuando no, pues no

```
showDiv(): void{
 if (corp.employee?.name == null){
  console.log('no tengo corporación');
 }else {
  console.log('Si tengo corporación');
 }
```

}

Cuando no tiene corporación por defecto el valor es `null`

¿Cómo puedo realizar esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La directiva `ngIf` siempre va a esperar como argumento una expresión *booleana*, por lo que **la función `showDiv` debe devolver un `boolean`**.

Por ejemplo,

```
public showDiv(): boolean {
  const name = corp?.employee?.name;
  // Forzamos la variable a boolean
  // Si name existe y no es un string vacío, entonces devuelve true
  return !!name;
}
```

O también puedes beneficiarte de la *type coercion* y escribir directamente tu expresión dentro del la directiva `ngIf`

```
<div *ngIf="corp?.employee?.name">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

También tienes la alternativa de mantener una variable `boolean` que vayas cambiando para mostrar u ocultar tu `div` (`<div *ngIf="showDiv">`)

```
// Por ejemplo...
public fetchCorp() {
  this.corp = ...;
  this.showDiv = true;
}
```

Hay muchas formas, de conseguirlo. Puedes leer [la documentación oficial de `ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) para conocer más.

Comment: Funciono muy bien, gracias leeré igual la documentación